# Spring Aspect does not run in test environment

Tags: java, spring, integration-testing, spring-aop

In my web system, I have an `AppConfig` class like this

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.mypackage")
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass = true)
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean
    public UrlBasedViewResolver setupViewResolver() {
        UrlBasedViewResolver resolver = new UrlBasedViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/pages/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        return resolver;
    }
}
```

I also create `Aspect` class in order to check the authentication when user triggers a request

```
@Component
@Aspect
public class AuthenticationAspect {
    @Before(value = "@within(com.mypackage.logic.aspects.SessionLookUp) || @annotation(com.mypackage.logic.aspects.SessionLookUp)")
    public void before(JoinPoint joinPoint) throws FailAuthenticationException {
        LogFactory.getLog(AuthenticationAspect.class).info("monitor.before, class: " + joinPoint.getSignature().getDeclaringType().getSimpleName() + ", method: " + joinPoint.getSignature().getName());

        ServletRequestAttributes attr = (ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes();
        HttpSession session = attr.getRequest().getSession(true);

        String username     = (String)  session.getAttribute("username");
        String role         = (String)  session.getAttribute("role");
        Boolean isLogined   = (Boolean) session.getAttribute("isLogined");

        if (
                session     == null || 
                username    == null || username.isEmpty()   ||
                role        == null || role.isEmpty()       ||
                isLogined   == null
        ) {
            throw new FailAuthenticationException("You need to login first");
        }

    }

    @After(value = "@within(com.mypackage.logic.aspects.SessionLookUp) || @annotation(com.mypackage.logic.aspects.SessionLookUp)")
    public void after(JoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        LogFactory.getLog(AuthenticationAspect.class).info("monitor.after, class: " + joinPoint.getSignature().getDeclaringType().getSimpleName() + ", method: " + joinPoint.getSignature().getName());
    }
}
```

with the `SessionLookup` interface

```
@Component
@Target(value = { ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE })
@Retention(value = RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface SessionLookUp {}
```

This is my controller

```
@Controller
public class ApplicationController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    @SessionLookUp
    public String sayHello() {
            return "Hello";
    }
}
```

Now, when I run on the browser, I will got the exception with the message "You need to log in first", but when using the integration test, the test will pass the `Aspect` without saying anything

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@Transactional
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {
    ApplicationController.class,
    AuthenticationAspect.class,
    DatabaseConfig.class 
})
@TestExecutionListeners({ 
    DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class,
    DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener.class,
    TransactionalTestExecutionListener.class,
})
public class ApplicationControllerTest {

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {                    
         mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext).build();   
    }

    @Test
    public void testAuthentication() throws Exception {

        mockMvc.perform(
            get("/")
        )
        .andExpect(
            status().isOk()
        );
    }
}
```

How can I fix this one ?

Comment: What's the http status on the browser when you get "You need to log in first" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `@ContextConfiguration` is declared as

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {
    ApplicationController.class,
    AuthenticationAspect.class,
    DatabaseConfig.class 
})
```

You seem to be missing your `AppConfig` class which declares the Aspect configuration.

Note that you should probably remove `ApplicationController` and `AuthenticationAspect` as well as those will be included (and managed) by `AppConfig`.